# exclude category from get_posts?

Tags: categories, get-posts, exclude

getting posts by cat with get_posts but need to exclude another cat called london or id 10. is this possible?

best, Dc.

```
//  array(7,-10)
    $laargsM = array('category' => 7, 'posts_per_page'=>300, 'orderby'=>'title', 'order'=>'asc' );
    $la_shapes = get_posts( $laargsM );
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

as ['get_posts()'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) uses the ['WP_Query()' parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters), i would assume that this should work:

```
$laargsM = array(
    'cat'              => 7,
    'posts_per_page'   => 300,
    'orderby'          => 'title',
    'order'            => 'asc',
    'category__not_in' => array(10) 
);
```

Comment: thanks Michael & really good to know its uses the 'WP_Query()' parameters too...